# Multiple Spinners in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

Alright, I'm totally new to this -

What I'm basically trying to do is, in a single Android Fragment I've multiple Radio Buttons and Spinners. Only when a particular Radio Button is enabled, its corresponding Spinner is setEnabled(true) , depending on the item of a particular spinner which has been selected, I've to display a string in another fragment..

Everything works fine when,say,when I choose 2nd (index : 1 ) element of a spinner.. but when I choose the first element (index : 0 ) of any spinner, it goes to the last spinner and the string in the next fragment is displayed depending upon the first index of the last spinner!

Why is the problem occurring ? Here's my code snippet :

```
    head_spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    description = "First element of Spinner 1";
                    break;

                case 1:
                    description = "Second element of Spinner 1";
                    break;

                default:
                    description = "First element of spinner 1";
                    break;


            }


        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    head_spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position2, long id) {
            switch (position2) {
                case 0:
                    description = "First element of Spinner 2";
                    break;

                case 1:
                    description = "Second element of Spinner 2";
                    break;


            }

        }


        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    head_spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position3, long id) {
            switch (position3) {
                case 0:
                    description = "First element of Spinner 3";
                    break;

                case 1:
                    description = "Second element of Spinner 3";
                    break;

                default:
                    description = "First element of Spinner 3";
                    break;


            }
        }


        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    manager = getFragmentManager();


    head_btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onClick(View v) {


                                         Fragment f1 = new Description();
                                         FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                                         android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                                         Bundle args = new Bundle();
                                         args.putString("DESCRIPTION", description);
                                         f1.setArguments(args);
                                         ft.replace(R.id.group1, f1, "A");
                                         ft.commit();


                                     }

                                 }
    );


}
```

}

When the output should actual show "First element of Spinner 1" / "First Element of Spinner 2" - It gives "First Element of Spinner 3".

However, it works fine for other cases, any idea why its not working properly?

Comment: man fix your formatting. This is really hard to read in its current state.

Comment: I suspect that all the spinner objects are initialised with spinner 3 id.

Comment: sha has a good point,  please add to the code block where you set `head_spinner1`, `head_spinner2` & `head_spinner3` and also your layout xml file

Comment: Its initialized correctly. The point is : it works correctly for every index of every spinner starting from 1 onwards.. but only for the 0th index of any spinner, it goes to the last spinner and returns the value of the 0th index of the last spinner..